# Calculating variance with unknowable mean

Tags: variance, nonparametric

I commonly hear the above statement or something like it in gambling circles.  When applied to a game with a known set of parameters, it is true. But when applied to something like a sporting event, I don't think it is a proper characterization.

For example, consider a gambling game with a known set of parameters like Roulette. In American Roulette the probability of winning a bet on red is 18/38, with certainty. If I was to bet on red 10 times in a row and lose every time, I could be said to have experienced 'negative variance'.

However, things change when considering games with unknowable and unobservable parameters. I'm making up this data, let's just say that Lebron James has scored >20 points in 50% of his 900 games as an NBA player. That's a large sample size and the best estimate of his true probability to score >20 points would be 50%. Let's also say that in each of his next 10 games I bet on him to score >20 points and lose all 10 bets. I could also be said to have experienced 'negative variance'. But, it's more than just negative variance. I am estimating an unobservable true probability by fitting it to the data. So, there is additional error of an unknowable magnitiude in my estimate. Is there a term or concept that defines this additional error?

More formally:

We all know the formula for the sample variance:

$$s^2 = \frac{\Sigma(X_i -\bar X)^2}{n-1}  $$

Is there a name for the quantity $(s+)^2$ below?

$$ (s+)^2 = \frac{\Sigma(X_i -\mu)^2}{n-1}  $$

I'm using $\mu$ to represent the true mean. In the Lebron James example $\mu$ is unknowable and in the Roulette example it is known. There should be extra error, deviation, variance, uncertainty, bias, whatever, for this quantity vs $s^2$ when comparing the LeBron James example to the Roulette example. In other words: $E(s^2 - (s+)^2) = 0$ for Roulette $E(s^2 - (s+)^2) \not = 0 $ for Lebron.

Is this a thing? Is there a name for this 'extra error'?

Comment: You're using the term "variance" in two completely different senses and it's muddying the waters substantially. Please use variance in only its statistical sense (since this is stats.SE), and use a different term for the other thing (which is related to variance in the statistical sense but *isn't* variance as such).

Comment: $\Sigma(X_i -\bar X)^2 = \Sigma(X_i -\mu)^2- n (\bar X-\mu)^2$ $\hspace{6cm}$ $\hspace{3cm}$ $\hspace{2cm}$

Its derivation is quite simple: ...  $\hspace{6cm}$

$\Sigma(X_i -\bar X)^2 = \Sigma(X_i -\mu+\mu-\bar X)^2 \qquad\qquad$

$ = \Sigma(X_i -\mu)^2+\Sigma(\bar X - \mu)^2 - 2  \Sigma(X_i -\mu)(\bar X-\mu)$

$ = \Sigma(X_i -\mu)^2+n(\bar X - \mu)^2 - 2  (\bar X-\mu)\Sigma(X_i -\mu)$

$ = \Sigma(X_i -\mu)^2+n(\bar X - \mu)^2 - 2  (\bar X-\mu)\cdot n(\bar X-\mu)\qquad\qquad$

$ = \Sigma(X_i -\mu)^2+n(\bar X - \mu)^2 - 2 n (\bar X-\mu)^2\hspace{6cm}$

$ = \Sigma(X_i -\mu)^2- n (\bar X-\mu)^2$

Comment: I don't see anything "extra" here. Losing on red 10X should happen ~.2% of the time.

Comment: There is a qualitative difference between the deviation in results between a game with a known distribution, roulette example, and an unknown distributon that is approximated by fitting data to it, LeBron example.  In the case of statistically unlikely deviation in results in the roulette example we know that it's just unlikely. In the Lebron case, unlikely results might be from normal fluctuation AND our model parameters being wrong. Is there a concept or term that describes this mathematically? Or can only describe this difference in a long-winded manne

Comment: @Glen_b - What would you call the "other thing (which is related to variance in the statistical sense but isn't variance as such)"? And thank you all for your responses.

Comment: A deviation from expectation? When it's lower than expected, it would be a negative deviation from expectation.